# qsort comparing all zeros

Tags: c, qsort

I am trying to use qsort to sort an array of x-y coordinate structs pointers based on their y value, but q sort is not comparing the correct values. I am baffled at this point, can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

sort function:

```
 23 int sortFunc(const void * firsti, const void * secondi){
 24 
 25         const Coordinate* first = firsti;
 26         const Coordinate* second = secondi;
 27 
 28         printf("Comparing %f & %f\n", first->y, second->y);
 29         if(first->y < second->y){ return 1;}
 30         else if(first->y == second->y){ return 0; }
 31         else{ return -1; }
 32 
 33 }
```

print function:

```
 13 void printArray(Coordinate * array[], int size){
 14 
 15         int x;
 16         for(x=0; x < size; x++){
 17                 printf("Point %i : %f | %f\n", x, array[x]->x, array[x]->y);
 18         }
 19 
 20 }
```

and calling

```
79     qsort(pointArray, count, sizeof(Coordinate*), sortFunc);
80     printArray(pointArray, count);
```

yields

```
Comparing 0.000000 & 0.000000
Comparing 0.000000 & 0.000000
Comparing 0.000000 & 0.000000
Comparing 0.000000 & 0.000000
Comparing 0.000000 & 0.000000
Comparing 0.000000 & 0.000000
Comparing 0.000000 & 0.000000
Point 0 : 103.253334 | -12.472327
Point 1 : -3.283118 | -3.101071
Point 2 : 9.289474 | -0.459975
Point 3 : 14.029107 | -11.844076
Point 4 : -6.465595 | 14.704790
Point 5 : -5.764663 | 8.882765
```

any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison function is written as if you have an array of `Coordinate` structs, not an array of *pointers* to `Coordinate` structs.

Since you have an array of *pointers* to `Coordinate` structs, the comparison function will receive *pointers to pointers* to `Coordinate` structs as parameters. For this reason your comparison function should look as follows

```
int sortFunc(const void * firsti, const void * secondi)
{
  const Coordinate* const* first = firsti;
  const Coordinate* const* second = secondi;

  if((*first)->y < (*second)->y){ return 1;}
  else if((*first)->y == (*second)->y){ return 0; }
  else{ return -1; }
}
```

Comment: yup. Just got that. Thanks